# append value to xml node using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I'm trying to append a string between `<value></value>`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rs:alarm-request throttlesize="100" xmlns:rs="http://url.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.url.com">
    <rs:attribute-filter>
    <search-criteria xmlns="http://www.url">
    <filtered-models>
      <equals>
        <attribute id="0x1144f50">
        <value></value>
        </attribute>
      </equals>
      </filtered-models>
    </search-criteria>
  </rs:attribute-filter>
    <!-- Models of Interest -->
    <rs:target-models>
    </rs:target-models>
</rs:alarm-request>
```

I used the following code, but I'm keep getting:
Can't locate object method "appendTextNode" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList"

```
my $parser     = XML::LibXML->new();

# Insert devices MH to GETdevices_xmlbody template
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($current_working_dir.'\GETdevices_xmlbody.xml');
my $elem = $doc->findnodes('//rs:attribute-filter/search-criteria/filtered-models/equals/attribute/value');

# $elem->removeChildNodes();
$elem->appendTextNode('STRING');
```

Comment: If your XPath would match, then you could use something like `$elem->get_node(1)->appendTextNode('STRING');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `XML::Twig` too:

Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        '//rs:attribute-filter/search-criteria/filtered-models/equals/attribute/value' => sub {
            $_->set_text('STRING');
        },  
    },  
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( shift )->print;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rs:alarm-request throttlesize="100" xmlns:rs="http://url.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.url.com">
  <rs:attribute-filter>
    <search-criteria xmlns="http://www.url">
      <filtered-models>
        <equals>
          <attribute id="0x1144f50">
            <value>STRING</value>
          </attribute>
        </equals>
      </filtered-models>
    </search-criteria>
  </rs:attribute-filter>
  <!-- Models of Interest --> 
  <rs:target-models></rs:target-models>
</rs:alarm-request>
```

Answer (score 3):

You asked to get all the nodes matching your criteria. You need to loop over them.

```
my $elems = $doc->findnodes('...');
for my $elem ($elems->get_nodelist) {
   ...
}
```

Simpler:

```
my @elems = $doc->findnodes('...');
for my $elem (@elems) {
   ...
}
```

If you just expect exactly one, you could just grab the first one.

```
my ($elem) = $doc->findnodes('...');
```

Comment: This is only one part of the problem. The other is that the XPath does not match at all, because starting from `<search-criteria>` there's another namespace which has to be dealt with. So either `XML::LibXML::XPathContext` has to be used, or the XPath expression has to be rewritten to do only `/*[local-name()="element"]` matches.